# IE 8 blocks Google as "unsafe"

Tags: internet-explorer-8, blocking

So, out of the blue, I open up Internet Explorer to get my iGoogle page.  Instead, I get a blood red background with a white rounded box quote "**This website has been reported as unsafe - www.google.com - We recommend that you do not continue to this website**."

What gives?  I am quite certain that www.google.com is not some spyware spambot webpage.  What would make **IE 8 on a 32-bit Win XP sp3 Pro** box think that Google is unsafe?  How do I get rid of this?

The actual URL that is being blocked is http://www.google.com/ig?hl=en&source=iglk

Think Microsoft forgot to put on anti-trust deoderant because I smell somehting fishy with this.

Comment: When did you last update the Root Certificates in Windows Update?  These certificates indicate how trustworthy sites and programs are.

Comment: seems like some type of malware or man-in-the-middle attack, may want to do a virus scan to make sure.

Comment: Is the date/time set correctly on your computer?

Comment: I think I can rule out visus/spyware and date/time issues.  But the Root Certificates is an area I am not very familiar with.  What would I need to look for?

Comment: also, what happens if you go to 74.125.115.105?

Comment: the certificate is irrelevant ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cleared out the internet history, cookies, etc. and everything works.   Very strange indeed.

Answer (score 3):

Check your C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts file for a www.google.com entry.
If you find one your machine has (or had) malware that overrode the DNS/IP look up for the trusted site.  If you logged in to the blocked site, you probably gave your password to a third party.

[edit] Since you have a clean hosts file you can rule out local redirection.  Next try `nslookup www.google.com` and compare the results from a machine you know is clean (or try a reverse lookup of that IP on a clean machine to verify the IP is actually google's).  If that comes back suspect, check your DNS settings in your machine and your home router.  If not then I would start to suspect the configuration of your SSL certificates.

Comment: I don't see any entries for other than my localhost 127.0.0.1 entry

Answer (score 0):

Open a command window and "ping www.google.com".  You should see one of Google's IP addresses such as  74.125.224.115.  Unfortunately, Google maintains about a hundred different IP addresses in different ranges but [this web page](http://compnetworking.about.com/od/traceipaddresses/f/google-ip-address.htm) has what appears to be a reasonably complete list.  If your result is not in one of those ranges then it's very likely that you have some malware that's redirecting your Google references.

Then (if no problem above) try pasting that address into your browser in place of the URL and see what happens.  If you get your nasty message with a 74.125... IP address then the problem is most likely with your anti-virus software (though some sort of malware is slightly possible).  If you don't get the nasty message when pasting in a known good Google IP address then again I'd suspect malware.

Answer (score 0):

The date and time were the problem. I thought just fixing it wouldn't take care of the problem then I notice the date more carefully and noticed that it said 2013 not 2014. So tried that it worked for me cause it was funny that my laptop din't give me that problem but my netbook did.